# Matplotlib stacked histogram from Pandas is being cut by a strange line

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram, stacked-chart

something strange is happening in matplotlib.

I have a pandas dataframe and I'm making a stacked histogram using two of its columns. One column is floats that goes into the histogram bins. The other column is only 0's and 1's, which are used to separate the data into two stacks. My actual code is bit more complicated but it goes something like this:

```
print(df)

    df =
        col1    col2
        1.7       1
        2.4       0
        3.1       0
        4.0       1
        etc      etc

# First I separate the data by the 0's and 1's in col2
df_1 = df.loc[df['col2']==1]
df_0 = df.loc[df['col2']==0]
    fig, axes =
```

Plotting with matplotlib's histogram function works fine, sort of. If I call this:

```
fig,axes= plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)

n,bins,patches= axes.hist( [ df_0['col1'], df_1['col1'] ] , histtype='step', stacked=True, Fill=True)
```

...I get this very nice plot:

[image: Histogram 1: Works fine]

HOWEVER, something very strange happens if I flip the order of df_0 and df_1 when I call hist(). 
Like if I do this instead:

```
n,bins,patches= axes[0].hist( [ df_1['col1'], df_0['col1'] ] , histtype='step', stacked=True, Fill=True)
```

[image]

... I get a plot with the stacks flipped (as expected), BUT now the plot has picked up a strange artifact; there's like an invisible line that is cutting off and filling in some places of the graph with color.

What the heck is going on here? My first thought was that maybe column1 or column2 had NaN values or something, but I checked those and the column values are fine. Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: This might be the first verified plot of the mysterious Bermuda triangle.

Comment: Use `histtype='bar'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fill` is not a useful argument to `hist`. It is a valid argument, because you may fill any patch in matplotlib. However, here you do not have a closed patch to fill.

Instead you may be looking for the different `histtype` options that are shown in the [histogram_histtypes example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/histogram_histtypes.html).

- `histtype="stepfilled"`
- `histtype='bar'`

In this case they both give the same plot,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)

a = np.random.rayleigh(size=20)
b = np.random.randn(20)+3
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1" : np.concatenate((a,b)),
                   "col2" : [0]*20 + [1]*20})

df_1 = df.loc[df['col2']==1]
df_0 = df.loc[df['col2']==0]

fig,axes= plt.subplots(ncols=2)

n,bins,patches= axes[0].hist([df_0['col1'], df_1['col1']], histtype='stepfilled', stacked=True)
n,bins,patches= axes[1].hist([df_0['col1'], df_1['col1']], histtype='bar', stacked=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]